# eval expression within shell script returns exit code 1

Tags: bash, shell, eval, exit-code, packer

I am using ubuntu 18.04 to run a shell script, and the `eval` expression returns an exit code 1, even if I remove the `git clone` and the `echo` right before:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.10.2
echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.bashrc

eval "$(cat ~/.bashrc | tail -n +10)"

...
```

And here's the `tail -n +10 ~/.bashrc` (I just want to ignore the first 10 lines, specially where it says `# If not running interactively, don't do anything`):

```
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

If I run the same eval expression within the command line, and do `echo $?` it returns `0`.

Doing `exec bash`, `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc` as a substitute of the `eval` does not work as I am using a non-interactive shell.

Also, I can't remove `set -e` as I am using packer to build an image and I want to stop the build If I get an error.

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Why do you think you can't use those commands in a non-interactive shell?

Comment: Are you getting an error message along with the exit code?

Comment: What commands are you executing with `eval`?

Comment: @Barmar no error along with the exit code.. both `exec bash` and `. ~/.bashrc` didn't work as I get `asdf command not found`. I am running a few `asdf` commands after the `eval` if that's what you asking, and the script stops on the `eval`. I have printed a few `echo` to confirm that.

Comment: I mean what commands are in `tail -n +10 ~/.bashrc`, which you're trying to execute using `eval`?

Comment: Add `set -x` so you can see what commands are being executed by `eval` when it fails.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the post with the output of `tail -n +10 ~/.bashrc`. I already used `set -x` but it was hard to debug since it had too many lines. I will try again.

Comment: and if this has something to do with the commands inside `~/.bashrc`, why running `eval "$(cat ~/.bashrc | tail -n +10)"` on the console returns a proper exit code 0?

Comment: Why do you need to execute any of this stuff? Most of it looks like it's for interactive shells.

Comment: Instead of trying to source a portion of `.bashrc`, create a separate file that both you and your `.bashrc` can source in its entirety.

Comment: While `eval` has its necessary uses, they are much rarer than most people seem to think. There's almost always a better alternative.

Comment: I'd really need to see the `set -x` output, including the specific error, to offer a firm diagnosis -- but why are you sourcing `.bashrc` from a noninteractive script, instead of _just_ sourcing the files that define the `asdf` function you need? `.bashrc` is there to set up interactive environments; it's not _intended_ to be safe for scripts to use, and what you've got there is far too long for me to be interested or willing to audit it.

Comment: Also, `set -e` before an `eval` is a Very Bad Idea here, because it changes the meaning of the code you're `eval`ing to add new failure modes.

Comment: (really, I'd argue that `set -e` is **always** a Very Bad Idea, and should never be used by anyone ever for any purpose at all; see [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) demonstrating how `set -e` changes code's behavior in deeply unintuitive, version-dependent, context-specific ways, thus making that code basically impossible to desk-check)

Comment: ...yes, writing code with proper error handling _without_ `set -e` means doing a bunch of `|| exit` or `|| return` over and over, but at least the net effect of doing that is you get something reliable and consistent; `set -e` behavior is neither.

Comment: [Here's the `set -x` output.](https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQCWaXFA) (I couldn't add it to the post as it is too big).

Comment: The reason why I can't source the files is that I will need to use `asdf` later. Packer creates the image using the script, and then when I launch the server, I have a systemd service that uses `asdf`.

Comment: The file might have expired, [here's another one](https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQjbLDFg).